# What is the URL for PDP dev and staging

Tags: permissions, pdp, mi

What is the PDP URL to use for dev and staging integration tests?
what should be the value of PDP_SERVER_URL

Answer (score 0):

PDP URL for dev and staging are

DEV:
https://app-permissions-pdp-dev.octoproxy.dsv31.boxdc.net:443/pdp

STAGING:
https://app-permissions-pdp-staging.octoproxy.dsv31.boxdc.net:443/pdp